# How can we use multiple "\n" in c programming

Tags: c

In Python,we're using  `print( "\n" * 15)`. I wonder that how can we do this in c programming without `printf("\n\n\n....\n");`. Is there any function for it?

Comment: Are [GNU C extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) acceptable (`fputs((char[16]){[0 ...14]='\n'},stdout);`)?

Comment: reasons for downvotes:  (probables)  1) no code to show what you have already tried,  2) the answer will be very opinion based  3) no reason for trying to save a few keystrokes

Comment: @yasin Also, this is a pretty straight forward problem that all programmers should be able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own function.

```
int PrintLines(int n)
{
    int x;
    for( x =0 ; x<n ; x++ )
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use this method for printing multiple `'%'` or `'\0'`.

Comment: You might consider using `fputs("\n", stdout)` because there isn't any formatting being done. Or even `fputc('\n', stdout)` because it's just one character.

Comment: Did you mean to make your return type `Int`?

Comment: Ohh.i answered from my android phone.it captalizes first letters.

Answer (score 5):

C does not have a string repetition *operator*, but it does have a function you can use:

```
char newlines[16];

memset(newlines, '\n', 15);  /* <-- this function */
newlines[15] = '\0';
fputs(newlines, stdout);
```

Comment: Using puts wouldn't write additional \n ?

Comment: @Mr.E, good catch.  I switched to `fputs()`, which should not do that.  I just dislike using`*printf()` when in fact there is no formatting being done.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always you can make a loop between the number of new lines you want and make a print.

```
for(int x=0; x<15; x++){
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `fputc()` in a loop.

```
while (n>0) {
  n--;
  fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "precision".  Practical for up to a small number (e.g. up to 20 below)

```
int precision = 15;
printf("%.*s", precision, "\n\n\n\n\n" "\n\n\n\n\n" "\n\n\n\n\n" "\n\n\n\n\n");
```

Comment: I feel like this is a pretty round about way of doing things. The other answers using a loop are more practical.